Sifting Property of the Dirac Delta in the Limit as the Integration Interval Shrinks to Zero
The standard sifting property of the Dirac delta function, $\delta(x-a)$, is usually stated as:
$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x) \delta(x-a) \, dx = \begin{cases} f(a) & \text{if } a \in (\alpha, \beta) \\ 0 & \text{if } a \notin [\alpha, \beta] \end{cases} $$
for a continuous function $f(x)$. (The cases where $a = \alpha$ or $a = \beta$ may require special treatment or may be undefined depending on the convention).
I'm interested in the behavior of the sifting property when the integration interval shrinks to zero around the point $a$. Specifically, does the following limit hold, and if so, how can it be rigorously justified?
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x) \delta(x-a) \, dx = f(a) $$
My Thoughts:
Intuitively, this limit seems to make sense. As $\epsilon$ approaches zero, we are essentially isolating the behavior of the Dirac delta function at $x=a$. We can think of the Dirac delta as the limit of a sequence of nascent delta functions (e.g., a sequence of increasingly narrow and tall rectangles with area 1). As the interval shrinks, the rectangle becomes a better approximation of the delta function, and the integral should approach $f(a)$.
However, I'm looking for a more rigorous justification of this limit. In particular, I'm interested in:

Does this limit representation of the sifting property hold in general for continuous functions $f(x)$?
How can we prove this result using the formal definition of the Dirac delta as a distribution?
Are there any subtleties or caveats that I should be aware of when working with this limit?

Relevant References:
I've looked at standard texts on distribution theory (e.g., Friedlander and Joshi, Gelfand and Shilov) and Fourier analysis (e.g., Folland), but I haven't found this limit stated explicitly.
Any insights or references to relevant theorems would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, the limit you present is correct. The reason is that in the definition of the delta function it is implicitly (tacitly) assumed that its width is much smaller than any parameters appearing in the integral. Now of course one can try to relax this condition, by assuming that the delta function has a certain width, which also appears as a parameter in the test function $f(x)$ or in the integration bounds. However in general this leads to problems, and hence should be avoided in any serious applications. Mathematicians tend to be rigid in this respect.

From the first property you stated, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)\,dx = f(a)$.  Thus $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)\,dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(a) = f(a)$ since $f(a)$ is independent of $\epsilon$.
